# iOS UIImageView Layering question

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am sure this question has been answered in numerous places but I have no idea what keyword to search for to answer this question.  If anyone can link me to the answer that'd be great.

I'm not sure how to control which UIImageViews (which are all subviewed to the same view) cover the others visually.  In other words, if I subview a UIImageView to the same location as another UIImageView, the 2nd one that was added is always covering the first one.  I'm not sure how to do this either in the UI editor or in code.  So far I've been adding them in the order I want them to show up but I can't always do that.  Especially if I need to set UIImageView that's an IBOutlet and I need it to be on top of all the UIImageViews that I add programmatically.

Can someone show me how to do this programmatically and possibly how to set values in the UI editor?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UIView has several APIs to deal with these issues:

- When adding a subview:

  - insertSubview:aboveSubview:
  - insertSubview:atIndex:
  - insertSubview:belowSubview:
- Moving subviews around in their z-ordering:

  - bringSubviewToFront:
  - sendSubviewToBack:
  - exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:

More details on all of these can be found in the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) (of which UIImageView is a subclass.)

Answer (score 0):

This is done at the [UIView layer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) and is not specific to UIImageViews.

Views can be programmatically 'relayered' with the following UIView methods:

```
– addSubview:
– bringSubviewToFront:
– sendSubviewToBack:
– removeFromSuperview
– insertSubview:atIndex:
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
– exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
```

To do it to the XIB in Interface Builder, reorder the views listed on this view, bottom row is the frontmost object:

[image: xib view]